# IOS- Adding date and time in TableViewCell with text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

in my project i am working on comment section i take a `UITextfield` to enter a comment and a `UITableView` to show the comments when Post comment button pressed.
All i want to show the Current date and time along with the commented text in the same cell like as in faceBook which shows date and time with comment.
please suggest me some code what i have to apply to show it
currently i am using the following code to put text input to `UITableView`

here i created custom label in table view cell

```
detaillabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 55, 45) ];
        detaillabel.text = @"";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:detaillabel];
```

Post Comment codes:

```
    -(IBAction)postcomment:(id)sender;
    {
        NSError *error;

NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YY HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];

    detaillabel.text=dateString;

        NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSMutableDictionary *messageDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        NSArray *array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *messageString = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *datallist =[messageString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"message.plist"];

        if(commentsarray == Nil)
        {
            commentsarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }
        NSInteger contactid = 0;
        if(datallist)
        {
            BOOL isFileExist = [filemanager fileExistsAtPath:datallist];
            if(isFileExist)
            {
                commentsarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:datallist];


            }
        }
        if(commentsarray.count >0)
        {
            NSDictionary *dic = [commentsarray objectAtIndex:(commentsarray.count - 1)];
            NSInteger val = [[dic objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
            contactid = val+1;
        }
        else{

            contactid = 1;
        }

        [messageDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:contactid] forKey:@"id"];
        [messageDictionary setObject:messageText.text forKey:@"id"];

        [commentsarray addObject:messageDictionary];
        NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:commentsarray format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
        if(data)
        {
            [data writeToFile:datallist atomically:YES];

            [commentstable reloadData];
            //[messagingtable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: messagearray.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
            [commentstable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:commentsarray.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in save data: %@",error);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSDateComponent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/) and [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/). See Apple's [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i)